# cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole' to 'LoginRegister.Authentication.ApplicationUser'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the error as below for the code where in I try to authenticate user using role base.

> cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityRole' to
> 'LoginRegister.Authentication.ApplicationUser'

```
if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.Admin))
    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.Admin));
if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.User))
    await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(UserRoles.User));
if (!await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(UserRoles.User))
{
    await userManager.AddToRolesAsync(user, UserRoles.Admin);
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly? Is it a compile error or a runtime exception? What is the type of `user`?

Comment: Its giving error (new IdentityRole(UserRoles.Admin)) and (new IdentityRole(UserRoles.User));,UserRoles.Admin , user type is String